# What is the equivalent of a Dropwizard Task in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, dropwizard

Is there an equivalent concept of a [Dropwizard Task](http://dropwizard.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/core.html#tasks) in Spring Boot?

> A Task is a run-time action your application provides access to on the
>   administrative port via HTTP. All Dropwizard applications start with
>   the gc task, which explicitly triggers the JVM’s garbage collection.
>   (This is useful, for example, for running full garbage collections
>   during off-peak times or while the given application is out of
>   rotation.) The execute method of a Task can be annotated with `@Timed`,
>   `@Metered`, and `@ExceptionMetered`. Dropwizard will automatically record
>   runtime information about your tasks. Running a task can be done by
>   sending a `POST` request to `/tasks/{task-name}` on the admin port

The use case I have is creating a simple "task" to perform [an online backup of an embedded H2 database](http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#upgrade_backup_restore) on the [admin interface](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-customizing-management-server-port) in a Spring Boot application. The key requirement is that I do not want to expose this endpoint over the main HTTP port and network interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring Boot calls that an `Endpoint` (http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-endpoints). You just implement that interface (or use a base class) and create a `@Bean`.

Comment: Just a point of clarification, is it possible to change the HTTP method as in DropWizard (i.e. `GET` vs. `POST`)?

Comment: `Endpoint` is not an HTTP aware interface (eg it gets exposed as a JMX operation). Look at `MvcEndpoint` if you want HTTP (and the existing implementations).

Comment: Thanks, was able to find a good example of `POST` here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/endpoint/mvc/ShutdownMvcEndpoint.java

Comment: Lastly, is is possible to supply arguments? I didn't see that in any of the endpoint interfaces. Btw, DW has the following signature: ```public abstract void execute(ImmutableMultimap<String, String> parameters,
                                 PrintWriter output) throws Exception;```

Comment: For a web endpoint you just use normal Spring MVC mappings, so you can do anything you want really I think (example: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/blob/master/spring-cloud-config-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/context/environment/EnvironmentManagerMvcEndpoint.java). Additionally you could add `@ManagedOperation` annotations to public methods for the JMX support.

Comment: This is a big help. Might be useful to add to the docs as well. Thanks again Dr. Syer!